# Why is this bash script not changing path?

Tags: bash

I wrote a basic script which changes the directory to a specific path and shows the list of folders, but my script shows the list of files of the current folder where my script lies instead of which I specify in script.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
v1="$(ls -l | awk '/^-/{ print $NF }' | rev | cut -d "_" -f2 | rev)"
v2=/home/PS212-28695/logs/
cd $v2 && echo $v1
```

Does any one knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you set `v1` you execute `ls -t` *immediately*.

Comment: Are you expecting the script to change the working directory for the interactive shell that executes it? It can not do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current script makes no sense really. `v1` variable is NOT a command to execute as you expect, but due to `$()` syntax it is in fact **output** of `ls -t` at the moment of assignment and that's why you have files from current directory there as this is your working directory at that particular moment. So you should rather be doing ordinary

```
ls -t /home/PS212-28695/logs/
```

**EDIT**

> it runs but what if i need to store the ls -t output to variable

Then this is same syntax you already had, but with proper arguments:

```
v1=$(ls -t /home/PS212-28695/logs/)
echo ${v1}
```

If for any reason you want to `cd` then you have to do that **prior** setting `v1` for the same reason I explained above.

Comment: your suggested answer runs on terminal but not in script.

Comment: it runs everywhere. Of you need to clarify what "does not work" really means in your case.

Comment: will you please elaborate how can i implement this in bash script. Should i pass it in variable and then execute it

Comment: I do not understand what is the desired behavior then. You may want to rephrase your question to clearly state what is expected behavior otherwise noone will know

Comment: it runs but what if i need to store the ls -t output to variable

Comment: Then set `v1` *after* you do the `cd`, not before.